# Downloading only gmail's INBOX using offlineIMAP

Tags: email, gmail, imap, offlineimap

So my offlineimap.conf looks like this:

```
[general]
accounts = Gmail-raub

[Account Gmail-raub]
localrepository = Gmaillocal-mine
remoterepository = Gmailserver-mine
synclabels = yes
# This header is where labels go.  Usually you will be fine
# with default value (X-Keywords), but in case you want it
# different, here we go:
labelsheader = X-Keywords

[Repository Gmailserver-mine]
#This is the remote repository
type = Gmail
ssl = yes
remotepass = super-sercret-password
remoteuser = my-account@gmail.com
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
ssl_version = tls1_2

folderfilter = lambda folder: folder in ('[Gmail]/Drafts')

[Repository Gmaillocal-mine]
#This is the 'local' repository
# type = Maildir
type = GmailMaildir
localfolders = ~/mail/gmail_offlineimap
```

With the above settings I am able to download Drafts, but if I replace [Gmail]/Drafts folderfilter entry with the [Gmail]/Inbox, it starts as usual

```
offlineimap -d imap -c offlineimap.conf 
OfflineIMAP 6.7.0
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
Debug mode: Forcing to singlethreaded.
Now debugging for imap: IMAP protocol debugging
Now debugging for : Other offlineimap related sync messages
Account sync Gmail-raub:
 [imap]: Using authentication mechanisms ['GSSAPI', 'XOAUTH2', 'CRAM-MD5', 'PLAI
N', 'LOGIN']
 *** Processing account Gmail-raub
 Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993
 [imap]:   39:53.12 Account sync Gmail-raub imaplib2 version 2.52
 [imap]:   39:53.12 Account sync Gmail-raub imaplib2 debug level 5, buffer level
 3
```

and then authenticates and lists all the different mail folders I have. And then filter them all out because of my folderfilter setting. But then it just closes the connection:

```
    [...]
[imap]:   35:06.22 Account sync Gmail-raub state => LOGOUT
     [imap]:   35:06.22 Account sync Gmail-raub [sync] LOGOUT ()
     [imap]:   35:06.22 Account sync Gmail-raub state_change_pending.acquire
     [imap]:   35:06.22 Account sync Gmail-raub _request_push(IDEE11, LOGOUT, {}) = IDEE11
     [imap]:   35:06.22 Account sync Gmail-raub data=IDEE11 LOGOUT
    imap.gmail.com writer:
     [imap]:   35:06.22 imap.gmail.com writer > IDEE11 LOGOUT\r\n
    Account sync Gmail-raub:
     [imap]:   35:06.22 Account sync Gmail-raub LOGOUT:IDEE11.ready.wait
    imap.gmail.com reader:
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com reader rcvd 57
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com reader < * BYE LOGOUT Requested\r\n
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com reader < IDEE11 OK 73 good day (Success)\r\n
    imap.gmail.com handler:
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler _put_response(* BYE LOGOUT Requested)
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler untagged_responses[BYE] 0 += ["LOGOUT Requested"]
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler BYE response: LOGOUT Requested
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler terminating: 'connection terminated'
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler LOGOUT:IDEE11.ready.set
    imap.gmail.com writer:
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com writer finished
    imap.gmail.com handler:
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler state_change_free.set
     [imap]:   35:06.29 imap.gmail.com handler finished
    imap.gmail.com reader:
     [imap]:   35:06.30 imap.gmail.com reader poll => [(4, 1)]
     [imap]:   35:06.30 imap.gmail.com reader rcvd 0
    Account sync Gmail-raub:
     [imap]:   35:06.34 Account sync Gmail-raub ["<class 'offlineimap.imaplib2.abort'>: command: LOGOUT => connection terminated"]
     [imap]:   35:06.34 Account sync Gmail-raub _close_threads
     [imap]:   35:06.34 Account sync Gmail-raub call shutdown
    imap.gmail.com reader:
     [imap]:   35:06.40 imap.gmail.com reader finished
    Account sync Gmail-raub:
     [imap]:   35:06.40 Account sync Gmail-raub state_change_pending.release
     [imap]:   35:06.40 Account sync Gmail-raub connection closed
     [imap]:   35:06.40 Account sync Gmail-raub _get_untagged_response(BYE) => ['LOGOUT Requested']
     *** Finished account 'Gmail-raub' in 0:01
```

Why did it terminate the connection? Does it not like [Gmail]/Inbox? I also tried

```
# folderfilter = lambda folder: folder in ('[Gmail]/INBOX')
# folderfilter = lambda folder: folder in ('INBOX')
```

and either of them result in a different (but the same between them) error:

```
ERROR: getfolder() asked for a nonexisting folder 'INBOX'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't "like" `Inbox`, because the inbox's name is all uppercase, named

```
INBOX
```

---

Trying with a small Python script

```
import getpass, imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('pop.gmail.com', 'imaps')
M.login('user.id@gmail.com', getpass.getpass())

ret, data = M.select('INBOX', True)
print(ret, data)
M.close()

M.logout()
```

Comment: I actually did try [Gmail]/INBOX, but it said it did not exist (ERROR: getfolder() asked for a nonexisting folder 'INBOX'). Using INBOX also gives the same result.

Comment: It is just `INBOX`, maybe `/INBOX` with offlineimap. See updated answer.

Comment: Actually INBOX was the first thing I tried. I updated my question to include what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Plain INBOX works with the Python script. Maybe offlineimap needs the leading slash, e.g. `/INBOX`.